# Comparing two varchar fields for likeness

Tags: t-sql

I am attempting to write a piece of code that will compare two varchar columns where the amount of characters that match in each are weighted and assigned a value and I can use this value later on to determine if they are a "fuzzy" match or not. So far I have a function that strips numerics and spaces, I figure that I can use this as a starting off point.  Does anyone have any direction they can push me in or some advice?
Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the SOUNDEX function.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the type of Data**. Soundex , Metaphone ,Double Metaphone are  good for Human Names.But not good for comparing street address for example , editdistance (Levenshtein distance) might be used for fuzzy matching the street address.

Jaro–Winkler distance and Q-gram are other techniques used in fuzzy matching that comes to my mind.

Here is an implemention of **editdistance**.if you are wondering what it is.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=51540&whichpage=2

Comment: Thank you everyone for you responses!  Soundex looks like it will help me in what I am trying to accomplish.  I will let you know if I have any trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing to the same direction as @GilM, phonetic matching algorithm, there is also another option: **[Double Metaphone](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Metaphone#section_2)**. It is not built-in with SQL Server, as SOUNDEX, but find [here a T-SQL version](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=519&lngWId=5).